# read a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file in this format:

ServerName:srvrX1
IP:
Location:NY
OS:

ServerName:srvrX2
IP:
Location:NY
OS:Windows Server 2012
XYZ:

ServerName:srvrX3
IP:
Location:STK
OS: Win2k3

ServerName:srvrX4
IP:
Location:STK
OS:Win2k8

ServerName:srvrX5
IP:
Location:STK
OS: RedHat Linux 5

ServerName:srvrX6
IP:
Location:TKY
OS: Windows Server 2012

The number of fields could vary for each server and the number of empty lines between each server info is randm . I want the output in tabular format. I am new to powershell could someone please help.

Thanks a lot.
Nel

Answer (score 6):

You can split the content on two or more line breaks, then split each returned element again, parse the content and create new object for each element:

```
$content = Get-Content .\test.txt | Out-String

$content -split '(?:\r\n){2,}' | Foreach-Object{

    $pso = New-Object PSObject

    $_ -split '(?:\r\n)' | Where-Object {$_} | ForEach-Object{

        $var = $_ -split ':'
        $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $var[0].Trim() -Value $var[1].Trim()
    }

    $pso

} 


ServerName IP Location OS                 
---------- -- -------- --                 
srvrX1        NY                          
srvrX2        NY       Windows Server 2012
srvrX3        STK      Win2k3             
srvrX4        STK      Win2k8             
srvrX5        STK      RedHat Linux 5     
srvrX6        TKY      Windows Server 2012
```

Comment: @user2764554, you should accept this as the answer, especially since you said it worked perfectly.